# Twisted sheaves on tower of $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

Take the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ over a ring $W$.
We call $\mathcal{O}(q)$ the usual twisted line bundle.

Now take the map $f: \mathbb{P}^n\to\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by
$$[x_0,\ldots, x_n]\mapsto [x_0^g,\ldots, x_n^g]$$
for some fixed $g$.

Now take the inverse limit $X = \varprojlim \mathbb{P}^n$, where the transition maps are the map $f$, every time. Call $p : X\to\mathbb{P}^n$ the projection.

> What is the cohomology $H^r(X,p^*\mathcal{O}(q))$.

Of course, it vanishes for all $r \neq 0,n$.

I am trying to do it, but I am confused by the notation, and all the indexes.

I have an educated guess for $H^0$

$$H^0(X, p^*\mathcal{O}(q)) = \bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left( \bigoplus_{\{i_1,\ldots, i_j\}\subset\{0,\ldots, n\}, n_1 + \ldots, n_j = q}W \cdot x_{i_1}^{n_1/g^k}\cdot x_{i_j}^{n_j/g^k}\right)$$

**Motivation** My friend and I are reading a paper we just wrote. 
We don't want to make a mistake on this calcùlation. It's easy to make mistakes, with all those indices.

Comment: The basis should be indexed by points in the standard simplex with coordinates in $Z[1/g]$, which seems to agree with what you wrote. Similarly for any toric variety and the toric Frobenius.

Comment: Fantastic! What thank you so much :-)

Comment: The formula has errors.  How do you get confused about your own notation, if this is about your own work (given that the direct limits involved are not so complicated)?  Or are you borrowing from work of others which has you confused?  What does it mean to "read a paper we just wrote"?

Comment: @nfdc23 Which error? We are borrowing from work of others

Comment: You should be able to figure this out for yourself; this kind of computation is a student-exercise level, not at the level for Math Overflow.  Maybe what you are reading from others has errors?  Think about a special case (e.g., $n=1$).